# Nginx Configuration Issue with sub-domains on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have three web sites working with `NodeJS`. I want to publish with `NginX`, therefore have installed all its requirements. For my domain, I'd like to publish over `https`, whereas for sub-domains, I'd like to publish over `http`. My problem is that the publishing fails for sub-domains.

I have written the config files in `/sites-enabled`folder.

/default:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.my-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate     /var/www/my-domain/server/config/certificates/www_my-domain_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/my-domain/server/config/certificates/www_my-domain_com_nokey.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;
  return 301 https://www.my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name my-domain.com;
  return 301 https://www.my-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

---

/subdomain.my-domain.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name crm.my-domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/crm.my-domain.com.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

---

/subdomain2.my-domain.com:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name support.my-domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/support.my-domain.com.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```